# Graphene-Django: In schema combine Query-objects (only takes first argument)

Tags: django, reactjs, graphql, graphene-python, react-relay

I am trying to combine multiple Query schemas located in different apps in Django 2.1. Using graphene-django 2.2 (have tried 2.1 with same problem). Python 3.7.

The Query class only registers the first variable. As an example shop.schema.Query.

```
import graphene
import graphql_jwt
from django.conf import settings

import about.schema
import shop.schema
import landingpage.schema

class Query(about.schema.Query, shop.schema.Query, landingpage.schema.Query, graphene.ObjectType):
  pass

class Mutation(shop.schema.Mutation, graphene.ObjectType):
  token_auth = graphql_jwt.ObtainJSONWebToken.Field()
  verify_token = graphql_jwt.Verify.Field()
  refresh_token = graphql_jwt.Refresh.Field()

schema = graphene.Schema(query=Query, mutation=Mutation)
```

Why is it like this? Have something changed with classes in python 3.7? The graphene tutorial says this will inherit for multiple...

```
class Query(cookbook.ingredients.schema.Query, graphene.ObjectType):
    # This class will inherit from multiple Queries
    # as we begin to add more apps to our project
    pass

schema = graphene.Schema(query=Query)
```

I am exporting my schema to schema.json for using it with react relay. I do find my object "collection" Query schema from landingpage(the 3. variable). Relay returns:

> ERROR: GraphQLParser: Unknown field `collection` on type `Viewer`.
>   Source: document `AppQuery` file: `containers/App/index.js`.

Is it a problem with Relay reading my schema.json?

Answer (score 1):

1. In **setting.py** add a new file as **schema.py**
2. Combine your Queries and Mutations in **schema.py** as follows:

> import graphene
>
> import about.schema as about
>
> import shop.schema as projects
>
> import landingpage.schema as projects

then add:

```
class Query(about.schema.Query, shop.schema.Query, landingpage.schema.Query,  graphene.ObjectType):
        pass
class Mutation(about.schema.Mutation, shop.schema.Mutation, landingpage.schema.Mutation, graphene.ObjectType):
        pass
schema = graphene.Schema(query=Query, mutation=Mutation)
```

3. Configure your combined schema in settings.py as follows:

   GRAPHENE = {
   "SCHEMA": "core.schema.schema",
   }

Answer (score 0):

I managed to solve it shortly after writing this. My problem was that I had a Viewer object in every app. Because I find it useful to have a viewer-graphql-root, like this:

```
graphql'
  viewer {
    collection {
      somestuff
    }
  }
'
```

I moved the Viewer object up to the root schema.py like this:

```
class Viewer(about.schema.Query, landingpage.schema.Query, shop.schema.Query, graphene.ObjectType):
  class Meta:
    interfaces = [relay.Node, ]

class Query(graphene.ObjectType):
  viewer = graphene.Field(Viewer)

  def resolve_viewer(self, info, **kwargs):
    return Viewer()

class Mutation(shop.schema.Mutation, graphene.ObjectType):
  token_auth = graphql_jwt.ObtainJSONWebToken.Field()
  verify_token = graphql_jwt.Verify.Field()
  refresh_token = graphql_jwt.Refresh.Field()

schema = graphene.Schema(query=Query, mutation=Mutation)
```